# Generating row numbers in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have the following data:

```
salesid | date | rownum
---------+----------+-----
10001 |  2018-01-02 |  1
10006 |  2018-01-02 |  1
10005 |  2018-01-02 |  1
20001 |  2018-01-03 |  2
20002 |  2018-01-03 |  2
30001 |  2018-01-05 |  3
30003 |  2018-01-05 |  3
30004 |  2018-01-05 |  3
30007 |  2018-01-05 |  3
40005 |  2018-01-10 |  4
40001 |  2018-01-10 |  4
```

I would like to generate the column `rownum` according to the `date` field. I would like to keep the value in `rownum` same for the same date, and increase it if the date increases.

```
select salesid,
TO_DATE(created_at,'YYYY-MM-DD') as date,
row_number() over(partition by TO_DATE(created_at,'YYYY-MM-DD') order by TO_DATE(created_at,'YYYY-MM-DD')) as rownum
from <tablename>
order by TO_DATE(created_at,'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

But this doesn't give me the desired result. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `dense_rank` and remove `partition by`.

```
dense_rank() over(order by TO_DATE(created_at,'YYYY-MM-DD'))
```